# How to create and retrieve a node by its label in Neo4j 2.0.0M5

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

My problem is really a basic example of using labels in Neo4j 2.0.M5. I try to drop all nodes and relationships, then I drop old 'Person' index, then I create a new 'Person' index based on 'name' property, then I create a node labeled 'Person' with name 'John Doe', to finally retrieve this node.

Cypher:

```
START n=node(*) MATCH n-[r?]-m  WITH n, r DELETE n, r
DROP INDEX ON :Person(name)
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
CREATE (n:Person {name:'Jhon Doe'})
start n=node:Person(name='Jhon Doe') return n
```

All works well, except at the end, when I try to retrieve my node. Neo4j throws an error :

```
Index `Person` does not exist
```

I try without creating the index, but it also doesn't work.

It's a really simple case, do you see the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Neo4j 2.0, `start` is no longer necessary, and your query can be expressed as:

```
match (n:Person)
where n.name='Jhon Doe'
return n;
```

With the `start` syntax, you're specifying an index name. With v2.0, when creating an index based on a label, I don't believe the index can be referenced by name (as it's never been given a name; you've just told Neo4j to index nodes with the label `Person` based on the property `name`). Since there's no index called `Person`, this is probably why you're seeing that error.

Comment: Thank you. Too bad it's not reflected in documentation for 2.0.